# Hot key for switch input focus to console in xcode

Tags: xcode

I know Shift+CMD+Y to show or hide console, but how to switch input focus to console? Which need me use mouse each time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Xcode 6.3 the shortcut is Shift+CMD+C

Update: Shift+CMD+C still works in Xcode 8

Update: Shift+CMD+C still works in Xcode 9.1